# using promises and async for protobufjs loadcall

Tags: javascript, protobuf.js

I am trying to figure out the best way to re-write the following code:

```
var api = function(id, contract) {
  var callback = function (error, root) {
    if (error)
      throw error;
    var by = Buffer.from(contract,'base64')
    var es = root.lookupType("Contract")
    var esMsg = es.decode(by)
    var esBytes = es.encode(esMsg).finish()
    signature = id.sign(esBytes).toString('base64')
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     protobuf.load("contract.proto", callback)
  })
}
var signContract = async(privateKey, contract) => {
  let signature
  var id = await crypto.keys.unmarshalPrivateKey(Buffer.from(privateKey, 'base64'))
  result = await api(id,contract,signature)
}

function getSessionSignature (hash, time) {
  return config.id + ":" + hash + ":" + time
}
module.exports = configure(({ ky }) => {
  return async function * signbatch (input, options) {

    var contracts = input.Contracts

      for (var i = 0 ; i < contracts.length ; i++) {
        contracts[i].contract = await signContract(config.PrivKey, contracts[i].contract)
      }

      //add signed contracts to the searchParams
      searchParams.append("arg", JSON.stringify(contracts))

      let res
      res = await ky.post('storage/upload/signbatch', {
        searchParams
      }).json()
      yield JSON.stringify({})
    } else {
      yield JSON.stringify({error:"Private key not found"})
    }
  }
})
```

My issue is how do I write the sign async code to pass in privateKey and contract variables to api var function and return the signature back to the result variable to be assigned to contracts[i].contract ? Please note that the id.sign(..) function is Promise inside the callback function.

Comment: var signature = id.sign(escrowBytes) ... is a Promise<Buffer>, so how do I return the value of the signature to signBatch ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to resolve the promise in the api function, the docs suggest you could use the single argument variant here, e.g.

```
var root = await protobuf.load("contract.proto");
... // (The code you currently by have in 'callback'
return signature;
```

As the generator is `async`, yield will emit a `Promise` which you can (obviously) handle with either `.then` or `await`